# Gitaly installation end without _build/bin/gitaly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitaly

I'm installing gitlab from source and I found this no 'gitaly' in bin folder. And 'bin' folder is totally missing in /home/git/gitalt/_build.

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake "gitlab:gitaly:install[/home/git/gitaly,/home/git/repositories]" RAILS_ENV=production
```

I have run it without errors and no idea here.

Can you help me? Any comment is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: my refrence doc is from:https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/installation.html#install-gitaly:~:text=Install%20GitLab%20Pages-,Install%20Gitaly,-Install%20the%20service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.

fixe it with changing account to git and doing without 'su'.

```
su - git && cd gitlab && bundle exec rake ...
```